# Expected at least 1 element matching "div#error_explanation", found 0.. Expected 0 to be >= 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a rails noob & can't make the connection of this error and the code while following Hartl's Rails tutorial.

Similar questions here @ stackoverflow don't solve the problem of my particular test failure error message as my partial code is same as Hartl's code on github and all other aspects of my integration testing pass green.

sample_app_3rd_edition/app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb

Here is my code from the integration test

/test/integration/password_resets_test.rb

```
       #Invalid password & confirmation
       patch password_reset_path(user.reset_token),
         email: user.email,
         user: { password:               "foobazz",
                 password_confirmation:  "barquux" }
       assert_select 'div#error_explanation'
```

which generates an error message referring to line 6:

```
test_password_resets#PasswordResetsTest (1442030711.19s)
    Expected at least 1 element matching "div#error_explanation", found 0..
    Expected 0 to be >= 1.
```

Next is the partial

/app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb

from which assert_select 'div#error_explanation' is supposed to render the error message needed for the invalid password and confirmation.

/app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
     <div id="error_explanation">
       <div class="alert alert-danger">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count,"error") %>
       </div>
       <ul>
         <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
           <li><%= msg %></li>
         <% end %>
       </ul>
    </div>
 <% end %>
```

I simply don't understand why assert_select is not working here since the _error_message partial works for all other tests referencing the same partial.  I think I understand that the integration test failure is telling me that "there is no message (element) where there should be one."

Help clearing up my confusion is greatly appreciated! I'll be happy to post UserController/ PasswordController or whatever @user variable code is needed.

updated 10/10/15 here is user.rb

> ```
> class User < ActiveRecord::Base
>    attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
>    before_save   :downcase_email
>    before_create :create_activation_digest
>    validates     :name, presence: true, length: {maximum:50}
>    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
>    validates :email,presence: true, length: {maximum:255},
>              format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
>              uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
> ```

```
   has_secure_password
   validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_blank: true
```

Here is the PasswordResetsController

> ```
> class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
>    before_action :get_user,         only:[:edit, :update]
>    before_action :valid_user,       only:[:edit, :update]
>    before_action :check_expiration, only:[:edit, :update]
> ```

```
   def new
   end

   def create
     @user = User.find_by(email: params[:password_reset]     [:email].downcase)
     if @user
        @user.create_reset_digest
        @user.send_password_reset_email
        flash[:info] = "Email sent with password reset instructions"
        redirect_to root_url
     else
       flash.now[:danger] = "Email address not found"
       render 'new'
     end
   end


   def edit
   end

   def update
     if password_blank?
       flash.now[:danger] = "Password can't be blank"
       render 'edit'
     elsif @user.update_attributes(user_params)
       log_in @user
       flash[:success] = "Password has been reset"
       redirect_to @user
     else
       render 'edit'
     end
   end

   private

     def user_params
       params.require(:user).permit(:password,
                                    :password_confirmation)
     end

     #Returns true if password is blank.

     def password_blank?
       params[:user][:password].blank?
     end

     #Before filters

     def get_user
        @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
     end

     #Confirms a valid user.
     def valid_user
       unless (@user && @user.activated? && 
               @user.authenticated?(:reset, params[:id]))
       redirect_to root_url
       end
     end

     #Checks expiration of reset token
     def check_expiration
       if @user.password_reset_expired?
         flash[:danger] = "Password reset has expired."
         redirect_to new_password_reset_url
       end
     end
 end
```

Comment: Did you test it yourself instead of using the automated test? Does the error_explanation `div` render when you reset a user's password and enter a mismatched new password and confirmation?

Comment: @Jason it works ok when I reset and enter a new password, but I will repeat to make sure I'm doing it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you are not rendering the shared/_error_messages.html.erb in your **app/views/password_resets/edit.html.erb** form.

```
<% provide(:title, 'Reset password') %>
<h1>Reset password</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user, url: password_reset_path(params[:id])) do |f| %>

      # Render the error messages!
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= hidden_field_tag :email, @user.email %>
```

Make sure that this is correctly inserted and the test should be successful!

Comment: if this answer responds to your question, could you accept it so the topic will be close? Otherwise I would be happy to help you further

Comment: I missed the <%= render......%>  at least 50 times I think. Thank you for the catch!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your User model (`user.rb`).  Somewhere, there should be a line `has_secure_password`.  This is a Rails method that adds the password and password_confirmation virtual attributes, along with their validations.

This is explained in section 6.3.1 of the Hartl Tutorial.

In the test, a user object is created with the password and password_confirmation attributes.  Posting to the `password_reset_path` attempts to save this user object.  Every time a model object tries to save, all model validations are run.  So without this `has_secure_password` validation, the user object was allowed to save, and thus you were seeing no error.

Comment: I posted user.rb to verify that has_secure_password is part of my User model. The source code sample_app_3rd_edition/app/models/user.rb is more advanced at this point in tutorial but is fundamentally the same?

Comment: Hmm.. Yes, that should still work the same.  Could you post your Password Resets Controller?  There might be something wrong with your update method there.

Comment: Password Resets Controller is up. Thank you for taking a look at it!

Comment: Well... that looks good too.  The update method should not succeed in updating the attributes (because of the has_secure_password validations), and the `else` condition should hit.  Then, the edit view should be rendered, showing the user error.  A couple more things:  Maybe post 'app/views/password_resets/edit.html.erb'.  That would be the last piece of the puzzle, where the errors partial should be rendered.
Also, as Jason suggested, try filling out the password reset form in the browser, put a different confirmation, and report back what happens.

Answer (score 0):

1) Failure:

```
HomeControllerTest#test_should_get_home [/home/ubuntu/workspace/test/controllers/home_controller_test.rb:11]:
Expected at least 1 element matching "title", found 0..
Expected 0 to be >= 1.
```

Comment: Please format...and elaborate what you are saying, and how it is an answer to the question. Congratz on your first answer, keep that up, but please try to make sure it is as useful as possible to as many people as possible by making it clear what it...is.